# Se puede hacer un Carousel Boostrap Dinámico

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap, slider, bootstrap-carousel

Estoy usando Angular.

Tengo un Carousel de boostrap en mi html y quiero hacerlo dinamico, es decir, tengo una lista con las **n** direcciones de ruta de las imagene y quiero cargarlas en mi carousel, el problema que tengo es que en todo lado que veo usan una cantidad **definida** de imagene por lo que simplemente copian y pegan el llamado a la imagen y cambian la direccion.

Este seria mi html, de momento estoy quemando tres imagenes ...

```html
  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active" style ="background-image: url('../../../assets/img/moptOscuro.png');"></div>
      <div class="carousel-item" style ="background-image: url('http://localhost:27210/#/AppData\Avisos\1061.png');"></div>
      <div class="carousel-item" style ="background-image: url('../../../assets/img/moptOscuro.png');"></div>     
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso, tengo los nombres almacenados en un DB, los recupero usando un Ajax y dentro de él armo los div con sus clases necesarias, quedando así:

```
    function GetEvidenceScrap(id)
{
    var idcompleto = id.id;
    var i = 0;
    var idbutton = idcompleto.substring(2, idcompleto.length);
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "Coordinador/GetEvidenceScrap",
            contentType: "aplication/json; Charset=utf-8",
            data: { 'idscrap': idbutton },
            async: true,
            success: function (result) {
                console.log("Longitud: " + result.length);
                while (i < result.length)
                {
                    var carousel = document.getElementById('CI_' + idbutton);
                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                        var div = document.createElement('div');
                        div.setAttribute('class','carousel-item active');
                        var img = document.createElement("img");
                        img.setAttribute('class', 'd-block w-100');
                        div.appendChild(img);
                        img.setAttribute('src', '/Evidence/' + result[i].rutevidencia);
                        carousel.appendChild(div);
                        i++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var div = document.createElement('div');
                        div.setAttribute('class', 'carousel-item');
                        var img = document.createElement('img');
                        img.setAttribute('class', 'd-block w-100');
                        div.appendChild(img);
                        img.setAttribute('src', '/Evidence/' + result[i].rutevidencia);
                        carousel.appendChild(div);
                        i++;
                    }   
                }
                console.log(result);
            }
        });
}
```

Del lado de HTML tengo los siguientes div con las clases faltantes así:

```
<div id="C_@item.IDScrap.ToString()" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
                                                <div id="CI_@item.IDScrap" class="carousel-inner">
                                                    <!--Creacion del carousel con evidencia-->
                                                    <!--Fin del carousel con evidencia-->
                                                </div>
                                                <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#C_@item.IDScrap.ToString()" data-bs-slide="prev">
                                                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                                    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
                                                </button>
                                                <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#C_@item.IDScrap.ToString()" data-bs-slide="next">
                                                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                                    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
                                                </button>
                                            </div>
```

En mi caso estoy utilizando C#, creo que puede servir como punto de partida para futuras consultas.